# How to start proving |f(x)| is integrable if f(x) is?

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, proof-writing, absolute-value

I've got the following question that I have very little idea on how to approach proving:
[image]

I was wondering if someone could send some hints/starter lines so that I actually know where this proof is headed? I'm unsure what exactly we're meant to do here :S

Comment: What definition of integrability are you using?  Are you talking Riemann or Lebesgue?  (The answer works either way, but the language changes).

Comment: Is this question part of an active exam?  It starts with "10 points"...

Comment: @Itay4 The answers in that possible duplicate don't appear to prove that $|f|$ is integrable (they assume that $|f|$ is integrable and prove the inequality).

Comment: Do you know Jensen' s inequality?

Comment: Not an active exam, previous assignments from earlier years; definition of Integral I'm familiar with is Riemann, and I do not know Jensens inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

One of the ways that integrability of functions $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is determined is as follows:

Let $f^+(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&f(x)>0\\0&f(x)\leq 0\end{cases}$ and $f^-(x)=\begin{cases}-f(x)&f(x)<0\\0&f(x)\geq 0\end{cases}$

Then, we can define $f$ to be integrable iff both $f^+$ and $f^-$ are integrable.  Then we define
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^bf^+(x)dx-\int_a^bf^-(x)dx.
$$

In the case of $|f|=f^++f^-$, we have 
$$
\int_a^b |f(x)|dx=\int_a^bf^+(x)dx+\int_a^bf^-(x)dx
$$

From here, since $\int_a^bf^+(x)dx$ and $\int_a^bf^-(x)dx$ are both positive (as the functions are positive), you can get the necessary inequalities directly.

Comment: Thanks for this, if I'm reading that right your saying that if f+ and f- are both integrable, we can show it is equal to or greater than due to the fact that:

|$\int$f(x)| <= $\int$|f(x)| due to the absolute function defined as f+ + f- whereas the absolute of the normal is just absolute (f+ - f-) which could be less than (basically triangle inequality)

Comment: It's hard to understand your comment, specifically, in the phrase "we can show it is equal to or grater than", I don't know what "it" refers to.

Comment: Mistyped, edited.

Comment: So, the correctness of this answer depends on the definition that you are using for integrability of functions.  Often, one develops the theory for positive functions and then extends this to all functions as hinted at above.  Then, I agree it's a direct application of the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this clears up what we're doing tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Pi$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.

It takes place that $\omega(|f|,\Pi)\leq\omega(f,\Pi),$ as for every sub-interval:

$$\omega(|f|,J)=\sup_{x,y\in J}(|f(x)|-|f(y)|)\leq\sup_J(|f(x)|-|f(y)|)=\omega(f,J)$$

Comment: What is omega representing here?

Comment: @PixelRain $\omega(f,J)=\sup_Jf-\inf_Jf=\sup_{x,y\in J}(f(x)-f(y))$

Comment: Ah I see, so just a direct application of Riemann sums def to prove it, alright!